# How to set Content Security Policy Headers in a Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm trying to make my Vue app secure, by eliminating clickjacking.

I'm not sure how to set the headers of the Vue server, the methods the X Frame or Frame Ancestor directives in a meta tag like:

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="X-Frame-Options: DENY:"
    />
```

However, the links below say that this is unsupported
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

I realise that for API requests, these headers should be set in the backend, however, this is to load the home page of the app (no api requests made).

How can I set these headers in my Vue.js server

Answer (score 1):

The homepage of the app is still loaded over HTTP.

The browser makes an HTTP request to get an HTML document. That HTML document includes `<script>` elements which cause the browser to fetch some JS. The browser runs some JS and uses it to modify the HTML document in the Vue app.

You should configure the `X-Frame-Options` and `Content-Security-Policy` to be served in the HTTP response headers for the response that delivers that initial HTML document which bootstraps the application.

---

The not-so-good approach is to set a CSP using a `<meta>` tag (in that same HTML document). You can't set `X-Frame-Options` that way.

Comment: How in the Vue server can I configue the X-Frame-options?

Comment: Since the Vue server is only there for development purposes that really doesn't matter. How you configure HTTP headers on your production server depends on which server software you are running.

Comment: My setup uses Vue, Django, and Nginx. Could this be set in Nginx?

Comment: Probably. It's your setup though. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=set+CSP+in+Nginx